# colorbox popup not opening after the page visited through turbolink

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, colorbox, turbolinks

I am using rails 4

I have a link  to open colorbox. colorbox  opens when page is reload. But it doesn't open when i click on the profile link after then i click on the same link.

My link is `<%= link_to "Upload Image", edit_seller_banner_users_path, class: "open-file-select1 photobox"%>`

and my js.coffee is

```
$(document).ready ->

  openFileForm = ->
    $(".photobox").colorbox
      width:"40%"
      height:"40%"
      escKey: false
      overlayClose: false

  loadMethods = ->
    openFileForm()

  loadMethods()

  $(window).bind "page:change", loadMethods
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Try also this

```
openFileForm = ->
  $(".photobox").colorbox
    width:"40%"
    height:"40%"
    escKey: false
    overlayClose: false

$(document).ready ->
  openFileForm()

$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  openFileForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need to fix colorBox library

https://github.com/sydneyitguy/colorbox/commit/11cb088358429c4fb80ced7da0c6b49f7285a084